# Changing icons in navbar on scroll

Tags: html, jquery, css

In my navbar I have two logos and a hamburger icon (for displaying the menu). When the user scrolls down, the navbar should change the background color, logos and hamburger should change color (from white to dark). I have managed to achieve that. But when you open and then close the menu after it has been scrolled, the hamburger icon disappears. I have tried many things (including adding classes to the hamburger button on scroll), but nothing worked. I have no idea, how to target "closing" button when the navbar is in scrolled state, so the "dark" version of hamburger button shows up.

```js
$(function(){
function e(){$(window).scrollTop()>0?(
    $("nav.nav").addClass("scrolled"),
    $(".content-nav").fadeIn(200)):(
        $("nav.nav").removeClass("scrolled"),
        $(".content-nav").fadeOut(200))
    };
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".cross").hide();
  $(".menu").hide();
  $(".hamburger").click(function() {
    $(".menu").slideToggle( "slow", function() {
      $(".hamburger").hide();
      $(".cross").show();
    });
  });

  $(".cross").click(function() {
    $(".menu").slideToggle( "slow", function() {
      $(".cross").hide();
      $(".hamburger-white").show();
    });
  }); 

  $( ".menu li" ).click(function() {
    $( ".menu" ).toggle();
    $(".cross").hide();
    $(".hamburger").show();
  });
});
```

```css
.landing-page-nav-container {
  background-color: #29428A;
}
.scrolled .landing-page-nav-container {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.logo-dark, .hamburger-dark {
  display: none;
}
.scrolled .logo-dark, .scrolled .hamburger-dark {
  display: initial;
}
.scrolled .logo-white, .scrolled .hamburger-white {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav navbar-fixed-top collapsed">
  <div class="landing-page-nav-container">
    <a href="<?php the_field('link_logo')?>">
      <img class="img-responsive img-nav img-logo-centrum logo-white" src="https://placekitten.com/50/50">
      <img class="img-responsive img-nav img-logo-centrum logo-dark" src="https://placekitten.com/49/50">
    </a>
    <img class="img-responsive img-nav img-logo-forum logo-white" src="https://placekitten.com/49/49"> 
    <img class="img-responsive img-nav img-logo-forum logo-dark" src="https://placekitten.com/50/49">      
    <button class="hamburger hamburger-white">
      <img class="img-responsive img-nav hamburger-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50/000000/FFFFFF">
    </button>
    <button class="hamburger hamburger-dark">
      <img class="img-responsive img-nav hamburger-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
    </button>
    <button class="cross" style="display: none">
      <img class="img-responsive img-nav hamburger-icon cross-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=cross">
    </button> 
    <div class="menu" style="display: none">
      <ul>
        <a href="#<?php the_field('about_link')?>"><li><?php the_field('about_napis')?></li></a>
        <a href="#<?php the_field('program_link')?>"><li><?php the_field('program_napis')?></li></a>
        <a href="#<?php the_field('registration_link')?>"><li><?php the_field('registration_napis')?></li></a>
        <a href="#<?php the_field('report_link')?>"><li><?php the_field('report_napis')?></li></a>
        <a href="#<?php the_field('lttalks_link')?>"><li><?php the_field('lttalks_napis')?></li></a>
        <a href="#<?php the_field('events_link')?>"><li><?php the_field('events_napis')?></li></a>
      </ul>
    </div>  
  </div>
</nav>

<script type = "text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in applying .show() on .hamburger, after clicking on .cross (which was messing in corect executing CSS).

Working jQuery code:

```
$(function(){
function e(){$(window).scrollTop()>0?(
    $("nav.nav").addClass("scrolled"),
    $(".content-nav").fadeIn(200)):(
        $("nav.nav").removeClass("scrolled"),
        $(".content-nav").fadeOut(200))
    };
});

$(document).ready(function() {

$(".cross").hide();
$(".menu").hide();
$(".hamburger").click(function() {
$(".menu").slideToggle( "slow", function() {
$(".hamburger").hide();
$(".cross").show();
});
});


$(".cross").click(function() {
$(".menu").slideToggle( "slow", function() {
$(".cross").hide();
   $(".hamburger-dark").removeAttr("style");
   $(".hamburger-white").removeAttr("style");
});
}); 

$( ".menu li" ).click(function() {
$( ".menu" ).toggle();
$(".cross").hide();
   $(".hamburger-dark").removeAttr("style");
   $(".hamburger-white").removeAttr("style");

});
});
```